# Android SQlite Database Location

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have read a lot and made the classes to make a SQlite database in my android applcation. Do I have to manually called my DBHelper class in my activity or is the `onCreate()` method automatically run?

Answer (score 0):

You must manually instantiate your helper class.  You could very well open in it your *onCreate()* method and make sure to call *close()* when onPause()/onStop() is called.

[Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) has a decent tutorial on implementing.